# Looping LINQ query using do while and display the result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on getting individuals who have not paid for the previous months

```
public ActionResult Arrears()
{
    int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    int i = 4;
    do
    {
        var subscriber = db.Subscriptions
            .Where(s => s.SubMonth == month && s.SubYear == year)
            .Select(s => s.UserName).Distinct().ToList();
        var alls = db.Members.Select(s => s.UserName).ToList();
        var notsubs = alls.Except(subscriber).ToList();
        List<Subscription> user = new List<Subscription>();
        List<Subscription> querie = new List<Subscription>();
        notsubs.ForEach(s => user.Add(new Subscription(s)));
        month = month - 1;
        i = i - 1;
        return View(user);
    } while (i != 0);
}
```

It gives me a list of the member who have not subscribed in the current month only and yet I want for the last 4 months

Comment: Don't do look-ups in a loop.  Instead you should do one look-up that returns all the non-subscribers for the 4 month period you are interested in.  Also you'll find it easier to query if you put the subscription month and year into a date column (if you have a day it would go there as well or you can just use 1).  Then you can do date range queries instead of having to do month range queries for various years.  `SubscriptionDate Between '2018-11-01' and '2019-02-28'` instead of `(SubYear = 2018 AND SubMonth Between 11 AND 12) OR (SubYear = 2019 AND SubMonth Between 1 AND 2)`

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

> It gives me a list of the member who have not subscribed in the current month only and yet I want for the last 4 months

You have a return statement inside your loop. Since there is no condition around the return statement, you will exit the loop during the first iteration.
The quick fix is to declare the **List user** variable above the loop and to write the return statement below the loop.

That being said, users who have subscribed during at least one of the last 4 months but not another one will appear in the resulting list. If this is not intended, you might want to consider removing the loop entirely and grabbing all your subscriptions of the last 4 months in one go.

Also note that you will have a bug between January and March of each year because the year of the Subscription and your year variable won't match. 
To avoid this, I would suggest not using the month and date as two separate fields but having a single field of type DateTime in your Subscription. You can then directly compare this field to DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4).

**Edit**:

With a DateTime field:

```
public ActionResult Arrears()
{
    DateTime minDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4);
    var subscribers = db.Subscriptions
      .Where(s => s.SubscriptionDate >= minDate)
      .Select(s => s.UserName);
    return View(
        db.Members.Select(m => m.UserName)
        .Where(u => subscribers.All(s => s != u))
        .ToList());
}
```

With a Month and Year Field:

```
public ActionResult Arrears()
{
    DateTime iterationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var subscribers = 
        db.Subscriptions.Where(
            s => s.SubMonth == iterationDate.Month 
                && s.SubYear == iterationDate.Year);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        iterationDate = iterationDate.AddMonth(-1);
        subscribers = subscribers.Union(
            db.Subscriptions.Where(
            s => s.SubMonth == iterationDate.Month 
                && s.SubYear == iterationDate.Year)
        );
    }

    var subscriberNames = subscribers.Select(s => s.UserName).Distinct();

    return View(
        db.Members.Select(m => m.UserName)
        .Where(u => subscriberNames.All(s => s != u))
        .ToList());
}
```

Note that with the first solution you're looking at exactly the last 4 months (2019-03-10), while with the second solution you're looking at all subscriptions since 2019-03-01. 
Note 2: these solutions will give you all members who have no subscriptions at all during the last 4 months. Is this what you need?